# Elegant way of copying list of directories to target directory

Tags: command-line, copy, xargs

Background: I have started using `beets` for managing my music collection. It uses the command line as the primary interface. The command `beet ls -ap` for example emits a list of paths (folders) that meet a given criterium (e.g. `added:2016-01` = added to library in Jan'16).

I have constructed the following rather complex command line for copying the last additions of my library *to a target directory* (think USB stick):

```
beet ls -ap added:2016-01 | xargs -I{} cp -R {} /target/directory/
```

My question: **is the `-I` option fiddling necessary** or am I missing a simpler way to accomplish the same task? My batch foo is regrettably weak...

Comment: If you use the `-t` (`--target-directory`) option of `cp` maybe? `somecommand | xargs cp -R -t /target/directory/`

Comment: @steeldriver:  that could have been your answer :$

Comment: I snoozed ;) as long as you get a good answer it doesn't really matter from whom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-t`

```
beet ls -ap added:2016-01 | xargs cp -R -t /target/directory
```

---

From `man cp`

```
-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
    copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```